# how cartodb.createLayer function works

Tags: carto, jquery, carto-js, cartocss

i am using cartodb.createLayer() function to prepare my web application. I have tried to pass vizjson url and metadata method both to get my layers from my carto account which has total of 8 layers in a map. But i am not able to render my map data on application, so far i have tried these two codes

cartodb.createLayer(map, {

```
      user_name: 'jayanttyagi',
      type: 'cartodb',
      sublayers: [{
        sql: query,
        cartocss: style,
      }]
    }).addTo(map)
```

And

cartodb.createLayer(map,
https://jayanttyagi.carto.com/api/v2/viz/b8d9ffd0-54c4-4e6d-9ab2-3ed6c3532dae/viz.json).addTo(map)

Here is the complete html document of the interface

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTYgja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
    <script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
    <style> 
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #buttons {
            position: absolute;
            top: 15px;
            left: 80px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button class="public">public</button>
        <button class="reset">reset</button>
    </div>

</script>
            <script type="text/cartocss" id="style">
        #layer {
          polygon-fill: #f43a15;
          polygon-opacity: 1;
        }
        #layer::outline {
          line-width: 1;
          line-color: #FFF;
          line-opacity: 0.5;
        }
          </script>

    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            map = L.map('map', {
          zoomControl: false,
          center: [16, 80],
          zoom: 10
            });
            cartodb.createLayer('map',{
          user_name: 'jayanttyagi',
          type: 'cartodb',
          sublayers: [{
            //sql: query,
            cartocss: style,
                }]
            }).addTo(map)

        /*cartodb.createVis('map',//'https://jayanttyagi.carto.com/api/v2/viz/3c941684-5cde-4591-b40a-46cb75a3ae0c/viz.json') 
            'https://jayanttyagi.carto.com/api/v2/viz/3a6b2aa5-fd29-4479-a216-cb65d232657c/viz.json', {
            zoom: 14, 
            layer_selector: true,
            shareable: true,
            legends: true
        })*/
        .done(function(vis,layers) {
                var plotlayer = layers[1].getSubLayer(0);
            });
            $('.public').click(function(){
                plotlayer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM parks WHERE parks='park_name' ");

            }); 
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255729/cartodb-createlayer-function-use @Jayant Tyagi you have posted the same question, regarding the first approach we do not know what is stored in `style` and `sql` variables, and the 2nd approach is going to fail [because BUILDER viz.jsons are not supported by the current version of CARTO.js](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations)

Comment: Sir, i have commented the query and the style code is here <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }, AND please ingnore my previous query as it doesnt had enough details

Comment: You are mixing things. That's the style of the document. So again, we need the **whole code** because it looks like it is failing not because of CARTO, but because there are something wrong in the code. [Here](http://bit.ly/createLayer-sample) you have a working example of a complete CARTO.js application code.

Comment: Okay, i am actually doing the edits in the sample code which you have provided just by doing the necessary changes @ramiroaznar

Comment: however this map is visible in createVis function but why not in createLayer function @ramiroaznar

Comment: The map will render but there is not compatibility if you want to interact with the vizjson. **Again**, we need to see the whole HTML code to see what is wrong with your code in the case of `createLayer`.

Comment: i have added the complete code please review @ramiroaznar

Comment: Did you figured out the error @ramiroaznar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of errors:

- The sublayer is created without pointing to a right SQL and CartoCSS parameters.
- There is not basemap.
- The function in the `done` promise should have only `layer` as argument.
- Finally, the button is not going to work because you do not have any `park` column in `plot` dataset.

I recommend studying really close CARTO.js documentation and check any examples available. Here [are](https://plnkr.co/edit/MV044lIDJ4ysLq1BhyE5?p=preview) my corrections.

Posdata: please do not ping GIS SE users outside this forum.

Comment: Thank you so much @ramiroanazar i m sorry to ping u outside this forum i was running short of time to compete this project

Comment: Please, if my answer solves your problem, mark it as solved.